# How do you enforce custom Exception in java with ArchUnit

Tags: java, exception, archunit

I want to use ArchUnit to enforce usage of only custom exception created specific to project to throw for uniform exceptions with pre defined error codes. How do we enforce this via ArchUnit
I see some examples for logging etc., but is this possible to enforce exception with ArchUnit?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for actually thrown exceptions in the current ArchUnit version 1.0.1 (cf. feature request [ArchUnit #886](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/issues/886)). Note that [`JavaCodeUnit`'s `getThrowsClause()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaCodeUnit.html#getThrowsClause()) is only about the method signature.

As exceptions that are thrown are usually instantiated before, you can try to find those constructor (or maybe factory method?) calls. For example, the following rule might catch *(pun intended)* many `RuntimeException`s:

```java
@ArchTest
ArchRule no_plain_RuntimeExceptions = noClasses()
    .should().callConstructorWhere(describe("target is a RuntimeException", call ->
            call.getTargetOwner().isAssignableTo(RuntimeException.class)
    ));
```

Please edit your question if you want to ask about a more specific use case.